# How do I achieve custom paging with just one textbox as an input/output?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a page where I just save one value "Name" to a field in the database and
based on that I would like to create some paging logic, so that I can page
between the different values, displaying them in the TextBox txtName. The
"Deleted" is there so that I can do a soft delete by just passing a datetime.now
to the field instead of actually deleting it.

How could this best be achieved since the id is a guid I cant really do any
comparison as to if the value is greater then or smaller then, this leaves me to
use the "Name" column for paging and the sorting is not important at all. It
does not matter if they are sorted or not.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnFirst" Text="|<" runat="server" OnClick="btnFirst_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnPrevious" Text="<" runat="server" OnClick="btnPrevious_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" Text=">" runat="server" OnClick="btnNext_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnLast" Text=">|" runat="server" OnClick="btnLast_Click" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" value="" MaxLength="30" runat="server" />
```

```
protected void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

```
------------------------------
| Id    |  Name    | Deleted | 
------------------------------
| guid  |  Adam    | NULL    |
| guid  |  Savage  | NULL    | 
| guid  |  Nick    | NULL    | 
| guid  |  Rick    | NULL    | 
| guid  |  David   | NULL    | 
| guid  |  Jeremy  | NULL    | 
| guid  |  Susan   | NULL    | 
| guid  |  Nija    | NULL    | 
| guid  |  Reko    | NULL    | 
------------------------------
```

Comment: If it doesn't matter if they are sorted or not, why don't you sort them by Name? Are the names unique?

Comment: Yes the names are unique.